# Read CSV file that needs data sanitization prior to loading into dataframe

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, sanitization

I'm reading a CSV file into pandas. The issue is that the file needs removal of rows and calculated values on the other rows. My current idea starts like this

```
    with open(down_path.name) as csv_file:
    rdr = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in rdr:
        type = row['']
        if type == 'Summary':
            current_ward = row['Name']
        else:
            name = row['Name']
            count1 = row['Count1']
            count2 = row['Count2']
            count3 = row['Count3']
            index_count += 1
        # write to someplace

,Name,count1,count2,count3
Ward Summary,Aloha 1,35,0,0
Individual Statistics,John,35,0,0
Ward Summary,Aloha I,794,0,0
Individual Statistics,Walter,476,0,0
Individual Statistics,Deborah,182,0,0
```

The end result needs to end up in a dataframe that i can concatenate to an existing dataframe.

Braindead way to do this is simply do my conversions and create a new CSV file, then read that in. Seems like a non-pythonic way to go.

Need to take out the summary lines, combine those with similar names (Aloha 1 and Aloha I), remove the individual stat info and put the Aloha 1 label on each of the individuals. Plus i need to add which month this data is from. As you can see the data needs some work :)

desired output would be
    Jan-16, Aloha 1, John, 1,2,3

Where the Aloha 1 comes from the summary line above it

Comment: Does pd.read_csv() fail if you do not remove the rows (i.e. are the lines invalid csv lines)? Do you know where in the file these lines will be located?

Comment: Please show the relevant parts of the csv file.

Comment: Added the start of the file. Comment also added to show that remove summary lines, put in label and month on the individual lines.

Comment: read_csv works fine, but now i'm having to remove rows, modify contents of each row and add columns

Comment: You can do these manipulations using Pandas directly, right? Pandas excels as data manipulation tasks. Why try to make these updates before getting the data into Pandas? Read the data into a DataFrame, do your filtering/modifying, then append the updated DataFrame you your other DataFrame. You can use Series.str.contains() to find appearances of 'summary', for instance, and filter them out.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Desired output would be:
Jan-16, Aloha 1, John, 35,0,0 (and maybe more)

Comment: I admit to being a dinosaur and to just learning Python. That's one of the reasons i'm doing this to learn. I'm on the old way of reading in the line, fixing, and then storing it off. Plus i have to do the conversion from the summary line onto the individual line and for my feeble brain that says read line at a time. If there is a panda way to group those and convert i'm very willing to try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal preference would be to do everything in Pandas.

Perhaps something like this...

```
# imports
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

# read in your data
data = """,Name,count1,count2,count3
Ward Summary,Aloha 1,35,0,0
Individual Statistics,John,35,0,0
Ward Summary,Aloha I,794,0,0
Individual Statistics,Walter,476,0,0
Individual Statistics,Deborah,182,0,0"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))

# give the first column a better name for convenience
df.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0':'Desc'}, inplace=True)

# create a mask for the Ward Summary lines
ws_mask = df.Desc == 'Ward Summary'

# create a ward_name column that has names only for Ward Summary lines
df['ward_name'] = np.where(ws_mask, df.Name, np.nan)

# forward fill the missing ward names from the previous summary line
df.ward_name.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)

# get rid of the ward summary lines
df = df.ix[~ws_mask]

# get rid of the Desc column
df.drop('Desc', axis=1)
```

Yes; you pass over the data more than once, so you could potentially do better with a smarter single pass algorithm. But, if performance isn't your main concern, I think this has benefits in terms of conciseness and readability.

Comment: This works very well. If i concatenate to another table the "order" of the columns doesn't matter but the matching descriptions do. It won't matter what the column order is for a month column, just that it's label matches the other tables label correct?

Comment: That's right. pd.concat() will match up columns based on their labels, regardless of their ordering in the frames you are concat'ing.

Comment: Thanks everyone. The penny just dropped and i get whats happening. Lots of power here in pandas.